# Memory leak at .csv download

Tags: php, memory-leaks, csv

Is it possible that the creation of a rather largge (20MB) .csv download creates a memory leak in case the user stops the download/export before the file has been saved on his machine?

If yes, how would you catch and counter this problem?

Comment: oh, thanks, a downvote without explanation!

Comment: "Dickishness" on the part of the original downvoter would probably be one explanation, I guess.

Comment: memory leak on server side ? or clients PC ?

Comment: one or two won't be a problem, if lots of connection by same user like user kept F5 the same page, probably it just make your server busier than usual + lots of disk I/O + network bandwidth choked (assuming your server is possible handle hundred connections at the same time), as for detecting this problem, connection handling seems possible, or u can consider using PID method, but none of them are perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but I would imagine it would get cleared up eventually. Either way, HTTPds are generally a lot more efficient at serving files than a server side language.

If you're worried, save the file (I assume we're talking about a dynamically generated file) to the filesystem (somewhere where the server can see it) and redirect the user to that URL.

For security (albeit through obscurity), make the filename something hideous (eg a hash of their username and a description of the file) and make sure people can't get a directory listing of the dir it lives in. Might make sense to date-tag the file (eg: filename-year-month-day.ext) so you can run something automatic to clean up the files after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating the file on the fly and streaming it to the user you may want to look at
http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php and perform some cleanup if the connection gets aborted or times out.